# Jenkins + Jfrog intregration via plugins - jar published has timestamp (date) appended

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I configured a Jenkins to deploy the artifact to Jfrog (community). This is what I want to have and instead what I have.

1. I have a spring-boot maven project "maven-example" with version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
2. Jenkins, due to the git push, start the building using the Build Environment : Maven3-Artifactory Integration
3. [image: This is the Artifactory Configuration]

4.In Build : Invoke artifactory Maven and used clean install goals

5. All seems to be ok. The artifact is published to my local artifact repository but when I browse it, I see the jar with date appended like in this picture

[image]

6. In a 2nd spring-boot project which depends on the maven-example, I would like to have :

   ```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>mavenexample</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
   ```

but I cannot retrieve the library if I do not use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>mavenexample</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-20200511.103423-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What I missed? (I already set the .m2 setting.xml to target my Jfrog)

Thank you in advance

Comment: The timestamps are the expected behaviour. Nevertheless, Maven should resolve `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` against the latest timestamp. If not, there is probably some configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior of Maven unique snapshots (as written by JF Meier in the comments).
Maven is using a high resolution timestamp to uniquely identify the snapshot version (this is the [only supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-UniqueSnapshotVersionsandClassifiers) snapshot type since Maven 3).